# Complex meta_query and orderby with multiple custom post types, and multiple date column names

Tags: mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to query two custom post types, `exhibitions` and `events`.

Exhibitions have `exhibition_start_date` and `exhibition_end_date` custom fields.

Events have a `event_date` custom field.

How would I go about sorting multiple columns in one orderby clause?

I've been looking at this for reference https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/.

Ideally my results would look like:

- Exhibition (Oct 2016)
- Event (Sept 2016)
- Event (Aug 2016)
- Exhibition (July 2016)
- Event (June 2016)

My query so far, which is not sorting properly:

```
$today = date('Ymd');
$past_date = date( 'Ymd', strtotime( $today . ' - 12 months' ) );

$args = array(
  'post_type' => array( 'exhibition', 'event' ),
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'exhibition_clause' => array(
      array (
        'key'     => 'exhibition_end_date',
        'compare' => '<',
        'value'   => $today,
      ),
       array (
        'key'     => 'exhibition_end_date',
        'compare' => '>=',
        'value'   => $past_date,
      )
    ),
    'event_clause' => array(
      array (
        'key'     => 'event_date',
        'compare' => '<',
        'value'   => $today,
      ),
      array (
        'key'     => 'event_date',
        'compare' => '>=',
        'value'   => $past_date,
      )
    )
  ),
  'orderby' => array(
    'exhibition_clause' => 'DESC',
    'event_clause' => 'DESC',
  ),
);
```

EDIT: after hooking into the 'posts_orderby' filter:

The filter:

```
function my_exhibition_event_date_posts_orderby( $orderby ) {
  if ( is_exhibition_event_query() ) {
    unset( $GLOBALS['is_exhibition_event_query'] );
    return "IFNULL(mt1.meta_value+0, mt2.meta_value+0) DESC";
  }
  return $orderby;
}
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'my_exhibition_event_date_posts_orderby', 10, 1 );
```

The sql output:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt3 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt3.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  ( 
    ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'exhibition_end_date' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value < '20161023' ) 
    AND 
    ( mt1.meta_key = 'exhibition_end_date' AND mt1.meta_value >= '20080623' )
  ) 
  OR 
  ( 
    ( mt2.meta_key = 'event_date' AND mt2.meta_value < '20161023' ) 
    AND 
    ( mt3.meta_key = 'event_date' AND mt3.meta_value >= '20080623' )
  )
) AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('exhibition', 'event') AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY IFNULL(mt2.meta_value+0, mt1.meta_value+0) DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

This still isn't right, though. This is the order the posts are returned in:

- Event (Oct 15, 2014)
- Event (Oct 16, 2014)
- Event (Oct 31, 2014)
- Event (Aug 6, 2014)
- Exhibition (Oct 14, 2016)
- Exhibition (Oct 22, 2014)

When they should be ordered by end date, with the most recent dates first.

Comment: What do your results look like right now with those args?

Comment: The posts returned are correct but the order is wrong. The orderby clauses have no effect.

If I change the orderby to reference the fields directly, the sort does have an effect. But, I need the orderby to combine the `exhibition_end_date` and `event_date` into a single order.

    `'orderby' => array(
      'exhibition_end_date' => 'ASC',
      'event_date' => 'ASC',
    ),`

Comment: Don't use the order by within args and instead order the array using php after you do your query. So get the data first, then a sort function like what is shown here to compare the values within the array. http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I wasn't able to figure out the proper query to get the order I wanted straight from the database. However, I did come up with an easy `usort` function to compare meta values.

To further complicate the SQL needed to order this, the `exhibition_start_date` is stored in the format `Ymd`, while the `event_date` is stored in format `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

```
usort( $the_query->posts, 'my_compare_exhibition_and_event_dates_descending' );

function my_compare_exhibition_and_event_dates_descending($a, $b) {
  $a_date = get_post_meta( $a->ID, 'exhibition_start_date', true );
  if ( empty( $a_date ) ) {
    $a_date = get_post_meta( $a->ID, 'event_date', true );
    $a_date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $a_date )->format( 'Ymd' );
  }

  $b_date = get_post_meta( $b->ID, 'exhibition_start_date', true );
  if ( empty( $b_date ) ) {
    $b_date = get_post_meta( $b->ID, 'event_date', true );
    $b_date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $b_date )->format( 'Ymd' );
  }

  return ( $a_date > $b_date ) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to place a hook for query `orderby` having roughly the following contents:

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'my_posts_orderby', 10, 1 );
function my_posts_orderby( $orderby ) {
    if (is_exhibition_event_query()) {
        return 'IFNULL(exhibition_end_date, event_date) ASC';
    }
    return $orderby;
}
```

You need to implement `is_exhibition_event_query()` to limit this query modification to this particular query. One option is to set a global variable before the query and unset it after the completion of the query.

**UPDATE**

The end query should look something like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
WHERE  
  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'exhibition_end_date' OR
    wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'event_date' )
  AND wp_postmeta.meta_value < '20161023'
  AND wp_postmeta.meta_value >= '20080623'
  AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('exhibition', 'event')
  AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

I'm not sure, if this is achievable via `WP_Query`. For non-trivial queries, I always use direct SQL queries instead (`wpdb->get_results()`). In addition to `posts_orderby`, there are similar hooks for the other parts of the query, so sometimes it is more straightforward to use `WP_Query` and tweak the query with one or more of these hooks.

Comment: Hi masa, thanks for the idea. I tried what you mentioned and think I'm closer, but the result still isn't correct. I've updated the answer with the sql output of the query. In the `posts_orderby` filter I'm returning this line `"IFNULL(mt1.meta_value+0, mt2.meta_value+0) DESC"`. Any ideas?

Comment: See UPDATE for more details.